# Get the name of the enclosing method from stacktrace (clojure)?

Tags: clojure

I have the following in a file "constraint.clj" starting at line 49 (shown with line numbers):

```
49 (defn stacker []
50   (let [s (first (.getStackTrace (new java.lang.Throwable)))]
51     {:name (.getMethodName s)
52      :file (.getFileName s)
53      :line (.getLineNumber s)}))
54 
55 (def s (stacker))
```

From nrepl, I compile the file. When I inspect the value at s, it shows.

```
app.constraint> s
{:name "invoke", :file "constraint.clj", :line 50}
```

So, basically, it seems to work pretty well, except that the getMethodName is not what I expected. I would like `:name` to be `app.constraint/stacker`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, Clojure generates a Java class inheriting from `clojure.lang.AFn` for each function matching the pattern "namespace$function-name". When a function is executed, the invoke method is called on that object, with the correct arity.

You can find the source here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java

If you want the original method, from the Java stack trace, you can look at the generated class name.

```
(defn stacker []
  (let [s (first (.getStackTrace (new java.lang.Throwable)))]
    {:name (clojure.main/demunge (.getClassName s))
     :file (.getFileName s)
     :line (.getLineNumber s)}))

(stacker) ;=> {:name "app.constraint/stacker", :file "constraint.clj", :line 50}
```

This information is also available directly through the function's metadata.

```
(meta #'stacker)
```

Comment: Use [`clojure.main/demunge`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.main/demunge) instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: Fixed. Another day, another function I never knew existed.